# How to enlarge UILabel width (letter spacing) in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, letter-spacing

This is the code I am using for the UILabel title of my View Controller:

`UIFont *bebasFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bebas" size:100];
RestaurantsTitle.font = bebasFont;
RestaurantsTitle.text = @"RESTAURANTS";`

and I need to enlarge the space between the letters of the title but I don't know how to do it.

Setting a width to the text field and not the frame would also work if that is also possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to enlarge the space between the letters

Use NSAttributedString and increase the kerning of the string.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/index.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSKernAttributeName

Comment: Example code from my book here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/iOS7bookExamples/bk2ch10p503attributedString/ch23p771attributedStringInLabel/ViewController.m

Comment: Than you so so much! I will figure it out with what you gave me :)